# How to use NULL column in WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, eloquent

I have some problems with query which has NOT EXISTING column, so when I try to do a query with WHERE. I get error about that Table has not this column 
`SELECT NULL AS users FROM test WHERE users = 1`
I know that query has not any meaning. But I need to do WHERE with column which does not exist in table

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) [mcve] is worth reading..

Comment: Rather than trying to achieve what you are thinking, better to share the end result you want to achieve. You might have better solutions.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to "Select * from table where A = '...' " but there column A is NOT in the table. If so there is no solution, it cannot be done. But I doubt you need to do that. Post your DDL, the query, and describe what you are trying to accomplish in non-sql terms. You may want to see [ask] as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IS NULL`

```
select column_name
from table_name
where column_name is null;
```

or `IS NOT NULL`

```
select column_name
from table_name
where column_name is not null;
```

Here you can see a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c449deb599c29f2e940f0308928692a)

Then, if you do not have that column in your table, you can use it like this:

```
with cte as
(select null as users
        , column_name
from table_name) 
select * from cte 
where users is null; -- you can replace this row with "where users = 1;"
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5dee5608ccc2f39197db00910cfb7d29) for that example

Comment: Thank you, but you already had column in TABLE. In my situation I have not this column so I can’t to check null is or no

Comment: @Aleks, I have updated my answer but do check the other answers also... Cheers !

Comment: Thank you vary much, Earlier I never heard about with!

Answer (score 0):

Use a *derived table*:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT NULL AS users FROM test
) dt
WHERE users = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in another SELECT

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT NULL AS users FROM test
) t WHERE t.users = 1
```